# Why Is the group ${\mathbb R}$ with the operation addition and group ${\mathbb R^{pos}}$ with the operation multiplication ISOMORPHIC

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

The function that makes this two groups Isomorphic was f(x) = $e^x$. I know Isomorphic groups are bijective. So my concern is if $\mathbb R^{pos}$ refers to all real positive number, how will negative element in $\mathbb R$ be to the $\mathbb R^{pos}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain of $f$ is taken as $\mathbb R$ and the range $\mathbb R^{pos}$. This map is a bijection  and a homomorphism [with $f^{-1}(y)=\ln y$].

Comment: Okay thanks. But my concern is, how will the negative element from $\mathbb R$ be mapped to $R^{pos}$. like $ f(-1) = e^{-1} $

Comment: I think you're confused about functions and/or bijections. Negative numbers $-x$, $x>0$ are all mapped to $e^{-x}$, which is a positive number.

Comment: $e^{x} >0$ for every real number $x$, even for negative $x$. @EALeben

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I was thinking that since $\mathbb R$ contains both $\mathbb R^{neg}$ and $\mathbb R^{pos}$, it means there will be some element (two elements) from $\mathbb R$ that will be mapped to one element in $\mathbb R^{pos}$

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as you have said, $-1$ is mapped to $e^{-1}$ which is a positive number.